# Why can't I delete movies from my iPhone 4, either from the phone or through iTunes? 

Tags: itunes, iphone

I was on vacation and took some videos, and now the iPhone 4 memory is near full.  So I tried to delete other experimental movies I made using Handbrake, so that I can take more video or photos, but if I plug the iPhone 4 into my Notebook computer, I can seem to delete it on iTunes?

Maybe because the computer I sync with the iPhone 4 is at home (a desktop), but not with me on vacation.

I can't delete it on iTunes, can't delete it on iPhone itself.  I am stuck during the vacation, or is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not a SuperUser-compatible answer, since the computer interface is missing, I just did the following:

1. Open the *iPod* app
2. Go to *Videos*
3. Swipe over a video from right to left
4. Press *Delete*
5. Confirm
6. Done!

No computer needed. Also works for music

Comment: this works!  the key is "wipe your finger from RIGHT TO LEFT on that row (of the list of videos)"... oh well, what kind of design decision is that?  Do you need ESP to know to do it this way?

Comment: @動靜能量 - No, you just need to read the [iPhone User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/iphone_user_guide.pdf), which Apple makes pretty easily available. That particular instruction is on page 66, under "Deleting Videos from iPhone".

Comment: hm... I think the assumption nowadays is people don't read manual -- when was the last time you read a manual on Chrome?  On Safari?  Or let's put it this way -- of the items you use, what's the percentage of manual you read?  5%, 10%?  Even if it is more, that means there is a good chance that the manual is not read by the user.

Comment: I tried that with an AudioBook and it worked. Thanks. However, when I connect my iPhone to the computer it shows as being there still. Why can't I remove it from iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anyway to delete music/video directly from the phone, without connecting back to the original iTunes and telling it to remove the file. If you're jailbroken you could SSH/SFTP into the phone and try removing the file from the phone but I'm not sure what affect that would have on the iPod's index of files.

I think you might be stuck until you can get back to the original system.